# I want to find which of the two tables associated with a table has the greatest sum of prices

Tags: sql, laravel, laravel-nova

**invoices table**

```
 - id
```

**charges table**

```
 - id - invoice_id - amount
```

**payment table**

```
 - id - invoice_id - amount
```

These are my tables. The scenario is the invoices table can hasMany either charge and payment. I want to sum amount of charge and payment and it will only return the scenario that the payment sum amount is lower.

I explained what I need and I would like to clarify when will I use it.

`Invoices::query()->` ... I want to chain my sql query here!

I hope I explained very clearly if you have question feel free to ask in comment

> Laravel elequent query would be best answer for me because I will use
> in my custom class that I created for my nova resource

Comment: I removed the conflicting DBMS tags. Please add only one tag for the database product you are really using.

Comment: The reason I added more than one is that it is not a problem to be found in other tags. The desired result is sql query. Forexample Im using postgresql but I can use mysql query.

Comment: Tagging an unrelated DBMS might result in answers that won't work with the one you are using. So it doesn't really help spamming the tags

Answer (score 0):

sql query is :

```
SELECT i.invoice_id
     , sum(p.amount) AS total_payments
     , sum(c.amount) AS total_charges
  FROM invoices AS i
  LEFT JOIN charges AS c
    ON c.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
  LEFT JOIN payments AS p
    ON p.invoice_id = i.invoice_id
 GROUP BY i.invoice_id
 HAVING sum(p.amount) < sum(c.amount)
```